# Function parameter - id vs object

Tags: node.js, typescript, function, parameter-passing, typescript-typings

I have some service that return user's data by it's id.
User already stored in request(session) - no need to fetch it every time.

The question is what is the best practice for parameter. Id of the user(SOLID) or user object(more validation/typings).

Example:

```
//...

// this
public async getByUser(user: User) {
  return await Transaction.findAll({
    where: { userId: user.id }
  });
}

// or this
public async getByUser(userId: number) {
  return await Transaction.findAll({
    where: { userId }
  });
}
```

Comment: Methods should only do what they are supposed to do. If it gets a user by ID, the only parameter provided should be an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either. Really.
Just keep the naming proper.

The more declarative your function names, the less confusion

```
//...

// this
public async getByUser(user: User) {
  return await Transaction.findAll({
    where: { userId: user.id }
  });
}

// or this
public async getByUserId(userId: number) {
  return await Transaction.findAll({
    where: { userId }
  });
}
```